# Undefined error on google spreadsheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I am desperately looking for some help about an error I keep getting when running a function on a Google Spreadsheet.

I have written all the code and I get two situations:

- if I run the script from the sheet where it is supposed to work, I get the error "Oops
  We're sorry. The server encountered an error. Please press "OK" to refresh the sheet" even though all the operations are actually completed below the error popup.
- if I run the script from another sheet the script is completed successfully.

I thought this problem could have been related to the active sheet function, so I started debugging to find a solution. I noticed I get absolutely no problems with all of the code except a part in which I ask the spreadsheet to make some operations on the columns: first to create a new one, then to resize two of them and eventually to delete one.

I am attaching all the code so that you can get a better idea of what the script is doing.

Thank you for your attention.

Tony

```
function forecastSettimanale() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var data = sheet.getDataRange();

// I need to operate on a column that has TOT written on its top, and its 
// position can vary

    var k = 1;
    while (k <= data.getNumColumns()) {
      var startRange = sheet.getRange(1, k, 1);
      var value = startRange.getValue();
      if(value == 'TOT') { 
        var flagColumn = startRange.getColumn(); // 
      }
  k++;
  }

  sheet.insertColumnsBefore(flagColumn, 1);

  sheet.setColumnWidth(flagColumn - 1, 40);

  sheet.setColumnWidth(flagColumn, 50);

  sheet.deleteColumn(flagColumn - 6);

  sheet.setColumnWidth(flagColumn, 100);

}
```

NEW edited code with your suggestion:

```
function forecastSettimanale() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var data = sheet.getDataRange();

var searchElement = 'TOT';
var firstRow = 1, firstColumn = 1, rows = 1;

var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, firstColumn, rows, lastColumn).getValues();
var flagColumn = range[0].lastIndexOf(searchElement) + 1;

sheet.setColumnWidth(flagColumn - 1, 40);
sheet.deleteColumn(flagColumn - 6);
sheet.insertColumns(flagColumn - 1);

var cellLeggiData = sheet.getRange(2, 3, 1);
var cellData = sheet.getRange(1, flagColumn - 1, 1);
cellData = cellData.setValue(cellLeggiData.getValue());


var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
var copiaDa = sheet.getRange(2, flagColumn, last_row - 1);
var copiaA = sheet.getRange(2, flagColumn - 1, last_row - 1);
copiaDa.copyTo(copiaA, {contentsOnly: true});

for (var i = 35; i <= lastRow; i+=33) {
  var cellaFormula = sheet.getRange(i, flagColumn, 1);
  var rigaPrecedente = i - 1;
  var totN = sheet.getRange(rigaPrecedente, flagColumn, 1);
  var totFore = sheet.getRange(rigaPrecedente, flagColumn - 1, 1);
  var letteraColonna = String.fromCharCode(64 + flagColumn);
  var letteraColonnaMenoUno = String.fromCharCode(63 + flagColumn);
  cellaFormula.setFormula("=" + letteraColonnaMenoUno + rigaPrecedente + "-" + letteraColonna + rigaPrecedente);
}

sheet.setColumnWidth(flagColumn - 1, 100);

sheet.showColumns(flagColumn - 6, 6);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce the problem. The code in question works without problem, as you indicate. Maybe you have to do some validations such as, for example, in `sheet.deleteColumn(flagColumn - 6);` What if `flagColumn` is less than 6?

I modified a bit the way to get the column that is needed.

```
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function forecastSettimanale() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var searchElement = 'TOT';
  var firstRow = 1, firstColumn = 1, rows = 1;

  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, firstColumn, rows, lastColumn).getValues();
  var flagColumn = range[0].lastIndexOf(searchElement);

  if (flagColumn > -1) {
    ++flagColumn;
    sheet.insertColumnsBefore(flagColumn, 1);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(flagColumn - 1, 40);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(flagColumn, 50);
    sheet.deleteColumn(flagColumn - 6);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(flagColumn, 100);
  }
}
```

Try to debug line by line to determine the method generates the error, that way it will be easier to find a solution.

Comment: I found something: when copying the copyTo range was a line bigger than the sheet, so it would create 30 extra lines at the bottom of the sheet. I tried it successfully on an empty sheet, thus meaning that the error is caused either by a data validation process or by an excessive amount of data on the sheet.

Comment: I updated the question pasting the whole script.
Again, thanks for your attention.